# Can running Firefox and Chrome at the same time cause problems?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, google-chrome

Can running Firefox and Chrome at the same time cause problems?

Sometimes when I switch from FF to chrome, where I have many more tabs up, the pages on chrome refresh slowly (1 second?), from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem here could be running out of memory or network congestion from having a data transfer intensive page open in the other browser (e.g. youtube video playing or streaming audio). Running more than one unrelated web browser at a time is certainly not a problem otherwise.

Short answer (all memory and processor requirements aside): No.

Comment: I just can back to edit my question to reflect that I was streaming video in one browser, and here is your answer.
Thanks a lot. Accepted.